# Como hago para que me separe una lista en dos listas

Tags: python

```
pi = [3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 6]
def corte(lista):
    bajo = []
    sobre = []

    for numerito in pi:
        if numerito :
            sobre.append(numerito)
        else:
            bajo.append(numerito)
    return [sobre, bajo]
print(corte(pi))
```

En if numerito : ,que debo agregarle para que la lista me la pueda separar dependiendo de cuantas cifras quiero que entren y queden en el mismo orden pero separadas por un corchete?

Comment: Si el índice del *numerito* es menor que el valor de la mitad del tamaño de la lista (calculado en algún lugar previamente) entonces va en `bajo` sino, va en `sobre`. Eso es lo que debes hacer.

Comment: cómo querrías que quede el resultado? podrías dar un ejemplo? fuera de eso, en el for dentro de la función deberías usar `in lista`, ya que pi es el array de afuera, pero lista sería el valor de entrada a la función

Comment: por ejemplo quiero que los tres primeros numeros me los coloque en una lista y los demas en una lista pero dentro del la lista asi:

Comment: por ejemplo la funcion es [1,2,3,5,6] y quiero que quede [[1,2,3],[5,6]]

Comment: ¿Y no puedes hacer simplemente `result = [pi[:3], pi[3:]]`? El cuerpo de la función se resumiría a `return [lista[:3], lista[3:]]`

Comment: Si lo haces en C sería una buena forma de hacerlo. En python sería calcular el valor de la mitad de la lista `round(len(pi)/ 2)` y como indica @JaimeMenéndez `return [lista[ :round(len(pi)/ 2)], lista[round(len(pi)/ 2): ]]`

Comment: entonces tal como dice  Jaime Menendez, si el número `n` es electivo, la solución correcta es `[pi[:n], pi[n:]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declara una variable indice para evaluar la posicion en tu lista y comparala con la mitad de la longidtud de la lista, así, si tu indice es mayor a la longitud comenzará a agregar en una lista u otra.

```
pi = [3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 6]
    
def corte(lista):
    
    bajo = []
    sobre = []
    i = 0 #Variable indice

    for numerito in lista:
        if i < round(len(lista)/ 2, 0): #si i < mitad de la longitud de pi (redondeado a 0 decimales)
            sobre.append(numerito)
        else:
            bajo.append(numerito)
        i += 1
    return [sobre, bajo]

print(corte(pi))
```

Este seria el output

```
[[3, 1, 4, 5], [9, 2, 6]]
```